# Trying to process the cube but getting the error at impersonation information

Tags: sql, bids, ssas-2008

I have built a cube in Business Development Intelligent Studio(BIDS) using some database with the name 'Test_cube' which consists of Products dimension table, customers dimension table and orders fact table.
The products table attributes :prodID-primary key,prodname,prodtype,prodcost
The customers table attributes :custID-primary key,custname,custloc
The orders table attributes :orderID,prodID,custID,quantity,unitprice,totalprice-calculated query column where primary key was set to orderID,prodID,custID

But I got some errors while trying to deploy the cube like

**Internal error : The operation terminated unsuccessfully.

The datasource,'Test_cube', contains an ImpersonationMode that is not supported for processing operations.

Errors in the high-level relational engine.A connection could not be made to the datasource with the DataSourceID of 'Test_cube',Name of 'Test_cube'.

Errors in the OLAP Storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'products',Name of the 'products' was being processed.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'prodID' attribute of the 'products' dimension from the 'Test_cube' database was being processed.

Server : The Current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

Double Click on your data source under solution explorer -> Navigate to `Impersonation Information` tab -> Choose `inherit`

Now try processing it again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but still after this also I'm getting some other error like OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.; 28000; Cannot open database "Test_cube" requested by the login. The login failed.; 42000.

Comment: Which option did you choose "service account" or "inherit"?You can grant access permission to 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. I am assuming SQL DB and SSAS are on the same machine

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,I got it.The Cube was processed successfully.

Comment: This works, but be aware that your SSAS instance may not be running under NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. Check to see which account is being used, and grant that account access.

Comment: You can run your SQL Analysis Service on "NT .. /NETWORK", then allow "mixed mode" in SQL Database Engine, then the "inherit" option works.

Answer (score 15):

I used 'Use a specific username and password' and typed in the username and password I use to log into my PC and it worked

Comment: Thanks, you've saved my time

Comment: Saved mine too :)

Comment: This worked for VS2019 and SQL Server 2019 also. Note that "credentials of the current user" and whatever Windows user you are, are _not_ the same thing. I think "current user" points to Visual Studio and that might make the difference. Anyway, specific Windows user worked still in late 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Answers are not fully complete , After you want to process cube or dimension , SSAS see Logon account in sql server analysis services service, if match, Process continue else Error.

You should use impersonation level to handle this issue.

First add your user to SSAS Server administrator
Right Click on Microsoft analysis service Instance and point Properties --> Security --> Server administrators --> add your account.

Then Go to Data Source properties --> Security settings --> Impersonation Info --> Use a specific windows user name and password --> and set your Username and password Server Admin.

Processing will be continue as well.

Answer (score 1):

**I had to set this to an explicit account and use my personal credentials to get around this problem.**

Particularly on a first deploy which I think could be relevant.

Also:  This problem went away after I started VS2012 in administrator mode.

And Finally: I suspect that the version of SSAS on your target could affect this behavior.  Think developer,enterprise vs standard edition.