# SSAS error: The following system error occurred: A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: ssas

I am trying to deploy my first Cube on a local instance. It first says deployment was successful but when I say "run" I get this screen:

[image]

My model is simple and I am using Wide world Importers DW with sale and city tables.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error "A device attached to the system is not functioning":

Well I tried some of the things mentioned here:
[Processing cube -Error-A device attached to the system is not functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147670/processing-cube-error-a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning).

To find the registry search for `regedit`  in windows.  I don't know if `psgetsid` from `pstools` is necessary.

For the Impersonation  error see here:

[Trying to process the cube but getting the error at impersonation information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598926/trying-to-process-the-cube-but-getting-the-error-at-impersonation-information)